# How to pass transclusion down through nested directives in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am trying to figure out how to pass a transclusion down through nested directives and bind to data in the inner-most directive. Think of it like a list type control where you bind it to a list of data and the transclusion is the template you want to use to display the data. Here's  a basic example bound to just a single value (here's a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/6qjWbNdWoG838I2Omnus?p=preview) for it).

html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <outer model="app.data"><div>{{ source.name }}</div></outer>
</body>
```

javascript

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', [function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.data = { name: "Han Solo" };

    ctrl.welcomeMessage = 'Welcome to Angular';
}])

.directive('outer', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="outer"><inner my-data="model"><div ng-transclude></div></div></div>'
    };
})

.directive('inner', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            source: '=myData'
        },
        template :'<div class="inner" my-transclude></div>'
    };
})

.directive('myTransclude', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: 'element',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            transclude(scope, function(clone) {
                element.after(clone);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, the transcluded bit doesn't appear. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it necessary to have a custom transclude directive?

Comment: have you tried transclude : {"inner":"inner"} instead of true?

Comment: Would you help me in understanding what you want the final output to be?  Should it be `<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div>Transcluded content here</div>`?

Comment: @Zach, ideally it would be <div class="outer"><div class="inner">Transcluded content here</div></div>. The ultimate goal is a datagrid-like control where the outer directive is provided a collection and creates an inner directive for each with the data for each item bound in the transcluded template. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Lenilson de Castro I originally tried without the custom transclude directive but couldn't get that working either.

Comment: @nixkuroi I haven't tried that, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Jason you don't need a custom transclude, actually the problem is with the scope that transclude are using to compile the template, checkout [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40113485/4488121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you don't have to use a custom transclude directive or any trick. The problem I found with your code is that transclude is being compiled to the parent scope by default. So, you can fix that by implementing the `compile` phase of your directive (this happens before the link phase). The implementation would look like the code below:

```
app.directive('inner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            source: '=myData'
        },
        template: '<div class="inner" ng-transclude></div>',
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return function (scope, elem, attrs) { // link

                transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                    elem.children('.inner').append(clone);
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

By doing this, you are forcing your directive to transclude for its isolated scope.

Comment: That's an interesting trick! Everything I've read says you shouldn't need to use the compile function anymore but this appears to be one case where it's still useful. I've marked this as the answer as it solves my original question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Zach's answer, I found a different way to solve my issue. I've now put the template in a separate file and passed it's url down through the scopes and then inserting it with ng-include. Here's a [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/JREa5f8StoCf9P2nzInN?p=preview) of the solution.

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <outer model="app.data" row-template-url="template.html"></outer>
</body>
```

template:

```
<div>{{ source.name }}</div>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', [function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.data = { name: "Han Solo" };
}])

.directive('outer', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            rowTemplateUrl: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="outer"><inner my-data="model" row-template-url="{{ rowTemplateUrl }}"></inner></div>'
    };
})

.directive('inner', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            source: '=myData',
            rowTemplateUrl: '@'
        },
        template :'<div class="inner" ng-include="rowTemplateUrl"></div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Looks good and much simpler than manipulating the DOM and compiling with the appropriate scope manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your transclude all the way down to the third directive, but the problem I see is with the scope override.  You want the `{{ source.name }}` to come from the `inner` directive, but by the time it compiles this in the first directive:

`template: '<div class="outer"><inner my-data="model"><div ng-transclude></div></div></div>'`

the `{{ source.name }}` has already been compiled using the `outer`'s scope.  The only way I can see this working the way you want is to manually do it with `$compile`... but maybe someone smarter than me can think of another way.

[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YikVdqDmX1H51XXcfxdl?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the info Zach, you got me going in the right direction. See my answer for how I ended up solving my issue.